# Is there a way to tell the last date when even any of the meta data property is modified using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I can see that transferring owner do not change modified date of the file. Is there a way to tell the last date when any of the meta data property is modified. I want to search for files based on change date and that change could be even owner change or folder change.
I am using google drive java api.

Comment: Watch maybe I cant remember how much it showed https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch

Comment: I am using google drive integration to crawl the data from user drive fully as well as incrementally(only changes after specified timestamp). Watch will not help me. I want to be able to know if file is modified(owner or lacation) or list of files whose owner or lacation or any other thing got changed recently(After given timestamp).